# number rows by variable, but start over when condition is hit

Tags: r, data.table, sequences

I want to number certain combinations of row in a dataframe (which is ordered on ID and on Time)

```
tc <- textConnection('
id              time       end_yn
abc             10         0
abc             11         0
abc             12         1
abc             13         0
def             10         0
def             15         1
def             16         0
def             17         0
def             18         1
')

test <- read.table(tc, header=TRUE)
```

The goal is to create a new column ("`number`") that numbers each row per `id` from `1 to n` until `end_yn == 1` is hit. After `end_yn == 1`, the numbering should start over.

Without taking the `end_yn == 1` condition into account the rows can be numbered using:

```
DT <- data.table(test)
DT[, id := seq_len(.N), by = id]
```

However the expected outcome should be:

```
id              time       end_yn   number
abc             10         0        1
abc             11         0        2
abc             12         1        3 
abc             13         0        1 
def             10         0        1
def             15         1        2
def             16         0        1
def             17         0        2
def             18         1        3
```

How to incorporate the `end_yn == 1` condition?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing there are different ways to do this, but here's one:

```
DT[, cEnd := c(0,cumsum(end_yn)[-.N])] # carry the end value forward

DT[, number := seq_len(.N), by = "id,cEnd"] # create your sequence

DT[, cEnd := NULL] # remove the column created above
```

Setting `id` as the key for `DT` might be worth while.

Comment: Very smart to carry the end value forward. This is exactly what I need and works much faster than my initial solution. Thanks!

Comment: What if I would want to give all entries the same number until the end_yn condition is hit? So give number the value 1 until end_yn=1 for the first time, then 2 until end_yn=1 for the second time, then 3 etc. (per coockie_id). seq_len(.N) needs to be replaced I think, but I cannot figure out with what

Comment: @MaxvanderHeijden, for that, you could try something like `DT[, number := cumsum(end_yn) + 1, by = "id"]`, but that would start numbering at `2` if `end_yn` is `1` for the first entry of an `id`. Try searching the data.table tag on SO, since a similar question may very well have been asked already.

Comment: Thank you. Of course I could also use the cEnd variable, since that essentially also makes a unique ID per journey. However not on a per ID basis, but that I don't really need after changing some other commands :)